# SKStoreProductViewController fails to present on iOS 17

Tags: ios, uikit, storekit, ios17

I experience a serious issue where calling `presentViewController: animated:` on `SKStoreProductViewController`

is executed and completion is called, but the view controller isn't visible on screen. The system thinks that it's the `presentedViewController`, and my `presentingViewController` is frozen. Tapping the screen prints a weird Console log of `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `SKStoreProductViewController`.

The code is executed inside an SDK that is integrated in apps, and the issue occurs only in some of the apps.

Any idea what could cause this issue? Thanks!

I expect the `storeKitViewController` to be visible but instead my `viewControllerToPresentFrom` is still visible but frozen.

```
    [viewControllerToPresentFrom presentViewController:_storeKitViewController
                                              animated:YES
                                            completion:^{
        if (completion) completion(nil);
    }];
```

Comment: Are you sure that SDK returns its callback on main thread? If not, consider wrapping modal presentation into dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {}); call.

Comment: Just because of the same issue Apple is rejecting my app for iOS 17. They persistently say Purchase screen is not pop-up.

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci did u manage to fix it?